# Flutter Application "won't run without Google Play service"

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

I am using the Android Emulator through Android Studio in order to implement an application that uses Google Maps, but when I run the application, I get this message on my emulator screen:

"google_maps_in_flutter won't run without Google Play services, which are not supported by your device."

and nothing else. I am still very very new to flutter and making apps in general, so this might be a very very easy fix. Let me know!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your emulator image probably does not have play services. In the AVD manager, create a virtual device and make sure it has the play store.

[image]

EDIT: You can also test on a physical device in debug mode